# Rspec Using Development Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.2 and rspec for testcases. I have set

```
Rails.env = 'test'
```

in both my spec_helper and rails_helper. Here is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_dev
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: root

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_test
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: root

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_prod
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: root
```

Here is my rails_helper:

```
Rails.env = 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include JsonHelper
  config.include PathHelper
  config.include S3Helper
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'yaml'
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |g|
      g.assets = false
      g.helper = false
      g.views = false
    end

    # Load all locale files
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join(
                              'config', 'locales', '**', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/workers/"]
    config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false
    config.active_record.schema_format           = :sql
    config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :hi, :mr]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :hi
    config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.5.3'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.9.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.4'

# Integrate the jQuery Validation plugin into the Rails asset pipeline
gem 'jquery-validation-rails', '~> 1.13.1'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# use swagger for api documentation
gem 'swagger-docs', '~> 0.1.9'

# for consuming restful web services
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.13.5'

# for ActiveRecord model/data translations
gem 'globalize', '~> 5.0.0'

# generates accessors for translated fields
gem 'globalize-accessors', '~>0.2.1'

# Amazon Web service SDK Ruby
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.1.0'

# cloud services for S3
gem 'fog', '~> 1.33.0'

# handle file uploads
gem 'carrierwave', '~>0.10.0'

# Photo Resizing
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.2.7'

# Background Jobs
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 3.4.2'

# Geocoder
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.2.9'

# active admin
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre1'

# for authentication
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.1'

# for roles of active admin
gem 'rolify', '~> 4.0.0'

# for authorization
gem 'cancan', '~> 1.6.10'

group :development, :test do
  # Debugging using pry
  gem 'pry-rails', '~> 0.3.4'
  gem 'pry-byebug', '~> 3.1.0'

  # testing framework for rails
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.4.1'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.8.0'

  # code test coverage
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.7.1'
  gem 'simplecov-rcov', '~> 0.2.3'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background
  gem 'spring', '~> 1.3.6'
end

group :development do
  # generates ER diagrams for rails application
  gem 'rails-erd', '~> 1.4.1'
end

group :test do
  # set of strategies for cleaning your database
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.3.0'
end
```

**When I run my test cases, Rails.env is 'test' as expected (used pry to verify).** **However my test cases are always hitting the development database.**

```
Rails.env
#=> "test"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
#=> {:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :database=>"app_dev", :pool=>5, :username=>"postgres", :password=>"root"}
```

spec_helper:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'simplecov'
require 'simplecov-rcov'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
SimpleCov.start

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  # Database Cleaner
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    Rails.application.load_seed
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end

SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::RcovFormatter
```

I have been scratching my head since last few hours but nothing seems to solve the mystery. Any help would be greatful!

Comment: Is it actually saving information to your dev db? Have you tried restarting your server?

Comment: @WesFoster : Yes. I did restart my server too. I have a users table with unique constraint on mobile_number. When I saw my test case failing, I used Pry and did a `User.all`. It showed up all my users in my dev database. Same for other tables also.

Comment: And how do you verify that your test hits development db?

Comment: Can you debug this `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config` ?

Comment: @dimakura: I am updating my question with these details. Thanks :)

Comment: What happens if you remove your dev database from your database.yml file and restart?

Comment: @Yule : Error on running rspec `'development' database is not configured. Available: ["test", "production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)`

Comment: If you add ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection to your rails_helper does that help?

Comment: @Yule: Something that finally works. It correclty sets my db to app_test when running rspec! Thanks a lot. Can you also explain me why do I have to explicitly `establish_connection` to make my rspec work correctly?

Comment: Since Rails 7 use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config` (this one is deprecated)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds as though somewhere in your environment (maybe one of your gems) it is setting your environment to dev or establishing a connection to your dev database.

To explicitly make it connect to the test database, add:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
```

to your rails_helper.

Prime candidate for troublemaker would be `gem 'rails-erd', '~> 1.4.1'. If you have this as auto-generating the diagram on migrate, when the test schema is migrated, it will connect to the dev database to dump a diagram.

Try removing this gem or perhaps the '.rake' file and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks You :) Your answer did help me correctly set the database to test  database. However I am still a little doubtful for the reasoning behind your answer. I will wait for some time more for a clearer answer else will mark your answer as accepted. Thanks a lot for looking into it. Please let me know if you require more details/file to debug on the odd behaviour of rails_helper

Comment: I'm glad I can help, and given I solved the issue - an upvote wouldn't go astray ;). Unfortunately it's impossible to say why this is needed as the code in your question does not give a reproducible instance. i.e. if i start a new rails project with nothing but your rails_helper, rspec and one test - I do not get the same issue. So the problem is elsewhere. Likely application.rb or one of your gems. Can you show these?

Comment: agreed and upvoted :). Also updated my question with application.rb and gemfile.

Comment: It is not the rails-erd gem which is causing the problem. I removed the gem and tested and got the same problem. I am adding my spec_helper file too if that helps.

Comment: I have marked it as answer because it came the closest to my question and the bounty was closing today. However the reasoning is still missing. thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I added `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'` in `spec_helper.rb` and it works 

Answer (score 13):

#### The reason your tests hit the development database is because you have defined `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` somewhere in your environment.

There are two ways of specifying the database connection to be used:

1. Specifying the `ENV['DATABASE_URL']`
2. Using the very popular `database.yml` file

**In many cases the first one takes prescedence over the latter.**

I realized I had a problem similar to yous after using ENV['DATABASE_URL'] to set my production database, only to find out that all my environments (test & development) suddenly had started to use my production database regardless of content in `database.yml`.

To solve my problem all I did was change the name on the environment variable to something else, so that it no longer overwrite my `database.yml` configurations.

#### Reading this will solve your problem:  [**Connection Preference information**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#connection-preference)

Comment: In my case, this was the correct answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for saving me. I have been looking for an answer for a month.

Comment: Their 'automatic merging' is really unexpected, thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 5):

Your `rails_helper` looks strange. The first line says:

```
Rails.env = 'test'
```

At the first line you don't have Rails loaded yet (I suppose you run RSpec using `bundle exec rspec`). So it should raise an error.

Therefore I made a small change in `rails_helper`:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
Rails.env = 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# the rest
```

Now putting

```
expect(ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:database]).to match(/test/)
```

somewhere in your spec, should pass successfully.

Comment: I already have a `Rails.env = 'test'` in my rails helper (mentioned it in my question above). Earlier i had a `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'` in my rails_helper and it did not set my env correclty. Hence I changed it to `Rails.env = 'test'` after suggestions on SO. (That helped. My env is now set correctly for test cases.) But it still hits the dev db and not test db.

Comment: Can you add `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'` just for checking in the first line? And where is Rails.env=`test` defined? Can you give full `rails_helper.rb`?

Comment: Sure. I am adding rails_helper.rb in the question above. Thank you :)

Comment: setting ` ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'`  as first line of my rails_helper does not help. Instead it shows my 'Rails.env' shows as 'development' when I run Rspec (checked using pry)

Comment: @AaditiJain I've updated my answer. But I'm curious how do you invoke RSpec?

Comment: I use `rspec` command to run my test cases. Also I tried solution mentioned in your answer but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @AaditiJain So you clain `expect(ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:database]).to match(/test/)` did not pass?

Comment: No it did not. Got this:    `Failure/Error: expect(ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:database]).to match(/test/)
       expected "app_dev" to match /test/
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -/test/
       +"app_dev"`

Answer (score 2):

My answer applies to anyone who is using Rspec with Ruby outside of Rails. For example, let's say you are creating a Ruby gem. Well, you can still add a database.yml in a config folder in your project and specify a test option:

```
test:
  adapter: 'mysql2'
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_bin
  pool: 1
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
  database: 'my_site_test'
```

Now you can add the following in spec_helper.rb:

```
  config.before :suite do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load(File.open(File.expand_path("../../lib/my_gem_config/database.yml", __FILE__)))["test"])
  end
```

The :suite scope indicates that the block of code should be run once before the suite of tests, that means all of your tests.

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me but I don't understand why I need to call it at all!

Answer (score 1):

1) Add `require: false` to the declaration of 'rails-erd' gem

```
gem 'rails-erd', '~> 1.4.1', require: false
```

2) In your *spec_helper.rb*, replace `Rails.env = 'test'` by `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'`

3) Verify in your *bin/rspec* (if present) that you don't have any instruction changing the value of `env`

4) Then stop spring from the command line

```
spring stop
```

5) Run your specs from the command line

```
rspec
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run rspc with `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec spec`

Also you can put inside `rails_helper.rb`

```
Rails.env = 'test'
```

Also move testing framework section from development test to test inside `gemfile`

```
group :test do
  # testing framework for rails
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.4.1'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.8.0'

  # set of strategies for cleaning your database
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.3.0'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"` at the top of rails_helper

Comment: No, that does not help :( . Also, as I have mentioned in the question, my `Rails.env` is set correctly to test during rspec (verified using pry). Thanks for looking :)